# RecyclerView scrollToPosition() - use screen bottom edge as reference point (instead of screen top edge)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView to load some Messages. Calling `scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1)` the view always loads to the end of the list.

**My problem:** I would like to add an offset to the scroll position so that new messages are not shown immediately but the user has to scroll down.
Meaning if i have 3 new Messages i would like to have an offset of 3 messages **from the bottom**.

The method scrollToPosition() seems to use the top of the view as reference point. Is there a way to load list items with an item offset from the botton?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method scrollToPosition() seems to use the top of the view as
>   reference point. Is there a way to load list items with an item offset
>   from the botton?

The best way to create Chat Message list screen with `RecyclerView` by set 
`reverseLayout = true` to make the messages list displaying from the bottom.

```
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
```

And you don't need to  call `scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1)` to scroll  to the bottom anytime you have new message. When you scroll to top now with `reverseLayout = true` is like you scroll the the bottom as your way above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - unfortunately this just reverses the way the list is displayed. i want to display the latest messages still at the bottom, but with a certain item offset. Meaning when i use an offset of 2, the view is scrolled 2 positions/ messages above the last.

Comment: Sorry my fault - i reversed the list itself in combination with your solution - works like a charm!